# Is there a way to send multiple values for grunt.option

Tags: gruntjs

I'd like start grunt with an option set with multiple vales.  Is this possible?
i.e.

`grunt doThis --ip 1.2.3.4 --ip 2.3.4.5`

Is this possible?

`grunt.registerTask('doThis', function () {
    console.log(grunt.option('ip'));
  });`

```
grunt doThis --ip="192.168.1.1" --ip="192.169.1.10"
Running "doThis" task
192.169.1.10

Done, without errors.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Grunt uses [nopt](https://github.com/npm/nopt) to parse the command line options and it supports multiple values. You'd pass them like this:

```
grunt doThis --ip=1.2.3.4 --ip=2.3.4.5
```

You'll need at least version `v1.0.0-rc1` of Grunt for this to work.

Comment: It seems to only pick the last option. I added my code above.

Comment: That's strange, I tested it before posting this. What versions are you using for `grunt-cli` and `grunt`?

Comment: Was just trying to upgrade my dependencies (ton of them) to test the latest version.  I'm currently on 0.4.4

Comment: Re-checked it and it works for me both with and without the quotes around the IP addresses. I'm using `grunt-cli v1.2.0` and `grunt v1.0.1`.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks for checking.  Looks like i need to upgrade :).  Appreciate the help.